# set some specific options in multiselect as disabled and selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiselect box having some options which i am able to select or disable via jquery, but i am not able to make them do both at the same time. How can i do that via jquery ??

Here's what i was doing - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tf5ZZ/)

In this example i am selecting an option on load and after that disabling it, but the option is still de selectable. I want to keep it selected and disabled all the time.

For now i am using click method to keep it selected by adding this line:

```
$('#multiSelect').click(function()
{$('#multiSelectoption[value="three"]').attr('selected',true);});
```

EDIT:
People are posting the solution where we select the option again on click, which i already have posted in my question. What i wanted to know is that if there exist some better solution as this one does not look good.

Comment: Just for reference purposes, jQuery's `prop()` method should be used for boolean properties like `selected` and `disabled`, and you can combine these together by passing through your properties as an object: `$('#multiSelect option[value="three"]').prop({
    disabled: true,
    selected: true
});`

Answer (score 2):

**js fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Tf5ZZ/5/

**jquery:**

```
//disabling on load:
$('#multiSelect option[value="three"]').prop('disabled', true);

$("#multiSelect option").on('click',function() {
    $('#multiSelect option[value="three"]').prop('selected',true);
});
```

Comment: I have posted this click solution in my question itself. Please check my updated question.

Comment: your fiddle shows that it is not always selected but just disabled. if we click on other option selection is lost. so just for that i used this code. you have written any code for click. you have just done it on load

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small piece of jQuery to solve your problem.

```
 $("#multiSelect option").click(function()
 {
      $("#multiSelect option[value='three']").prop("selected", true);
 });
```

Comment: Again, i already have this solution and was looking for more elegant one. Selecting the option again on clicking doesn't look nice. It has to look like a fixed option.

Answer (score 1):

If the point is to prevent the value of the select box from being changed after it's set then you should disable the select box instead of just the option item.

```
$('#multiSelect option[value="three"]').prop('selected',true);
$('#multiSelect').prop('disabled',true);
```

See this fiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/zKbVm/1/.

Also, the difference between `prop()` and `attr()` is that `attr()` gets/sets the element's attributes (which reflect the inital state of the element) and `prop()` gets/sets its properties (which represent the current state of the DOM node). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr for more information.

Comment: The point is to prevent only one of the option from getting changed while other options are still available.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could handle that in the create event of multiselect which is called after the widget gets created.

Below is the code snippet which I am using in the current application I am working on;

```
create: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function () {
        var checkBoxValue = $(this).val();
        // Using linq.js to query the fields and determine whether
        // the field is required in my case.
        // Replace this if statement with your own logic here
        if (Enumerable.From(CHAMP.cache.fields).Count(function (x) {
            return x.Id.toString() == checkBoxValue && x.IsRequired == true;
        }) > 0) {
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="3">
    <option value="1" selected>One</option>
    <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>Three</option>
</select>
```