# Jquery multiselect disable options based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

Using Jquery multiselect for dropdown. Am filling multiselect with some values and selecting data which user already selected(coming from DB), can i disable some options based on condition.
Here is my code

```
$.each(selectedGroups, function(){
    $("#usergroup_list").multiselect('select',this.id);
    if(this.name =="Viewer"){
     $('#usergroup_list option[value=\"'+this.id+'\"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

But this is not working

Comment: are you talking about simply using `$(element).attr('disabled', true)`  within the `loop` and `if` condition?

Comment: yeah. but can i do with in the loop given in question..??

Comment: assuming `this` is a jQuery element sure, `$(this).attr('disabled', true)` - also checkout `$(this).prop('disabled', true)`. I've never seen `multiselect` used before so not 100% sure.

Comment: please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201732/set-some-specific-options-in-multiselect-as-disabled-and-selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable some mutiselect options you can use this code

```
$('#multiSelect option[value="Viwer"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

this will make option having option Viwer.